# PowerShell 101: unexpected result using select-object piped into set-content

Tags: powershell

Here's my powershell script; I think the intent is pretty obvious:

```
import-csv .\CdmCodeList.csv | select-object -first 3 { 
    $id = $_.ItemDescription.Replace("'", "''");
    $mn = $_.ManufacturerName.Replace("'", "''");
    $mc = $_.ManufacturerCode.Replace("'", "''");
    "insert into @codes values ('$($_.ItemCode)', '$id', '$mn', '$mc')";
}
```

This does what I expect, outputting to the host:

```
insert into @codes values ('37025012', 'SAW BLADE PROFIX', '', '')                                                                                                                                                                
insert into @codes values ('37067808', 'ROD SUPER FLEX DANEK', '', '')                                                                                                                                                            
insert into @codes values ('52600200', 'GENERATOR PRECISION SCS ADVANCED BIONICS', '', '')
```

Now if I want to dump that to a file by adding this to the last line:

```
 | set-content -path "my.sql"
```

The resulting content of my.sql is not what I want, and very surprising to me:

```
@{ 
    $id = $_.ItemDescription.Replace("'", "''");
    $mn = $_.ManufacturerName.Replace("'", "''");
    $mc = $_.ManufacturerCode.Replace("'", "''");
    "insert into @codes values ('$($_.ItemCode)', '$id', '$mn', '$mc')";
=insert into @codes values ('37025012', 'SAW BLADE PROFIX', '', '')}
@{ 
    $id = $_.ItemDescription.Replace("'", "''");
    $mn = $_.ManufacturerName.Replace("'", "''");
    $mc = $_.ManufacturerCode.Replace("'", "''");
    "insert into @codes values ('$($_.ItemCode)', '$id', '$mn', '$mc')";
=insert into @codes values ('37067808', 'ROD SUPER FLEX DANEK', '', '')}
...etc...
```

Two questions: 1. What is PowerShell doing?  and 2. How can I get the file output to look like the host output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select-Object` produces objects. In the case of your script, it is producing scriptblocks. When you output to host, it is executing the scriptblocks in order to produce the output, but `Set-Content` is writing the actual scriptblocks.

If you change one little part of your script to pipe the output of `Select-Object` to a `Foreach-Object` (using the scriptblock as the body of the `foreach`), it will produce your desired output. Change this part of the first line:

```
select-object -first 3 {
```

To this:

```
select-object -first 3 | foreach {
```

Your final script should look like this:

```
import-csv .\CdmCodeList.csv | select-object -first 3 | foreach { 
    $id = $_.ItemDescription.Replace("'", "''");
    $mn = $_.ManufacturerName.Replace("'", "''");
    $mc = $_.ManufacturerCode.Replace("'", "''");
    "insert into @codes values ('$($_.ItemCode)', '$id', '$mn', '$mc')";
} | set-content -path "my.sql"
```

Comment: Perfect - thank you. The script works with your modifications, and knowing that my select-object was outputting _scriptblocks_ will help me in the future.

Comment: Well, it was outputting scriptblocks because you had the `{...}` section (which is the script block) as part of the call to `select-object`. Just to make that clearer. In other words, it was giving you scriptblocks because you gave it a template scriptblock.

Comment: That makes sense - I didn't realize powershell could handle scriptblocks just like any other object -- seems pretty powerful, if you're doing it on purpose.  :)  Thanks so much for the help and explanation.